# Is there a way to do Left Join in JPA using @Query which takes List of Object to be joined with?

Tags: sql, jpa, left-join, eclipselink, jpql

I've a requirement where I've a list of Object, which I've to use for a join, and should be passed as an argument in function.
For instance:

```
Class Dept{
  String deptId;
  String deptName;
  int order;
}

Class Person{
  String personId;
  String personName;
  int deptId;
}
```

```
So I've a list of Dept object.
List listOfDept;

Now I need to know if there's a way in JPA(JPQL) through which I can do something like this :
```

```
@Query( value = 'Select p from Person p where p.deptId = DeptObject.deptId (+) order by DeptObject.order')
List<Person> findPersonFromDeptListLeftOuterJoin( List<Dept> listOfDept )
```

Eg.[Image will help understand example better, in case of confusion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuP7W.png)

Comment: Does Person have a reference to Dept or just the deptId int value? "Select p from Person p outer join p.dept dept order by dept.order"  if so.

Comment: otherwise: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#ON try " Select p from Person p outer join Dept dept ON person.deptId = dept.deptId order by dept.order"

Comment: @Chris No there's no reference of Dept in Person, there's no such mapping.
Thanks for the link, I'll try that.